# How to access the nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I want to access nested JSON object values by iterating.

I tried `console.log(test[0].Invoice[0].Cost.NO[0]);` but it's not working.

```js
var test = [{
  "Invoice": {
    "NO": "869",
    "$$hashKey": "object:186"
  },
  "Cost": [{
    "NO": 183,
    "Amnt": 100
  }, {
    "NO": 184,
    "Amnt": 200
  }]
}, {
  "Invoice": {
    "NO": "698",
    "$$hashKey": "object:189"
  },
  "Cost": [{
    "NO": 110,
    "Amnt": 150
  }, {
    "NO": 142,
    "Amnt": 263
  }]
}];

console.log(test[0].Invoice[0].Cost.NO[0]);
```

Comment: I tried this. **console.log(test[0].Invoice[0].Cost.NO[0]);**

Comment: add this to your question

Comment: i see no [JSON](http://json.org/)!

Answer (score 1):

Your code `console.log(test[0].Invoice[0].Cost.NO[0]);` won't work.

Because `Invoice` and `Cost` are same level objects (`Cost` isn't nested in `Invoice`).

Check below example on how to access them.

You would need to understand [Arrays []](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Objects {}](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

```js
var test = [{
  "Invoice": {
    "NO": "869",
    "$$hashKey": "object:186"
  },
  "Cost": [{
    "NO": 183,
    "Amnt": 100
  }, {
    "NO": 184,
    "Amnt": 200
  }]
}, {
  "Invoice": {
    "NO": "698",
    "$$hashKey": "object:189"
  },
  "Cost": [{
    "NO": 110,
    "Amnt": 150
  }, {
    "NO": 142,
    "Amnt": 263
  }]
}];

// To access COST
console.log(test[0].Cost[0].NO);

// To access Invoice
console.log(test[0].Invoice.NO);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your JSON:

```
var test = [{
  "Invoice": {
    "NO": "869"
  },
  "Cost": [{
    "NO": 183,
    "Amnt": 100
  }, {
    "NO": 184,
    "Amnt": 200
  }]
}, {
  "Invoice": {
    "NO": "698"
  },
  "Cost": [{
    "NO": 110,
    "Amnt": 150
  }, {
    "NO": 142,
    "Amnt": 263
  }]
}];
```

`console.log(test[0].Cost[0].NO);` 
would be 183

You can check your structure in development with `console.log(test)` if you are not used to JSON.

To iterate you should use a loop as described here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp

Short example:

```
 var myFunction = function(item,index){
    console.log(item.Cost[0].No);
 }
 test.forEach(myFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

`test` is an array thus you need to iterate over it.

Each iteration will give you an object with 2 properties : `Invoice` and `Cost`

`Invoice` is again an object thus you only need to access the property you need

`Cost` is an array thus you need to iterate each items which are objects

```js
var test = [{
  "Invoice": {
    "NO": "869",
    "$$hashKey": "object:186"
  },
  "Cost": [{
    "NO": 183,
    "Amnt": 100
  }, {
    "NO": 184,
    "Amnt": 200
  }]
}, {
  "Invoice": {
    "NO": "698",
    "$$hashKey": "object:189"
  },
  "Cost": [{
    "NO": 110,
    "Amnt": 150
  }, {
    "NO": 142,
    "Amnt": 263
  }]
}];

test.forEach(t=>{
  console.log("Invoice N°: " + t.Invoice.NO);
  t.Cost.forEach(c=>{
    console.log("- Cost N°: "+ c.NO + " - Amount: " + c.Amnt);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong statement

`test[0].Invoice[0].Cost.NO[0]`

It should be as below

```
 test[0].Cost[0].NO
```

Because Invoice and Cost are properties of same json object.

try out this

```js
  var test = [{ "Invoice": { "NO": "869", "$$hashKey": "object:186" }, "Cost": [{ "NO": 183, "Amnt": 100 }, { "NO": 184, "Amnt": 200 }] }, { "Invoice": { "NO": "698", "$$hashKey": "object:189" }, "Cost": [{ "NO": 110, "Amnt": 150 }, { "NO": 142, "Amnt": 263 }] }];
 

  console.log(test[0].Cost[0]);
 console.log(test[0].Cost[0].NO);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var test = [{ "Invoice": { "NO": "869", "$$hashKey": "object:186" }, "Cost": [{ "NO": 183, "Amnt": 100 }, { "NO": 184, "Amnt": 200 }] }, { "Invoice": { "NO": "698", "$$hashKey": "object:189" }, "Cost": [{ "NO": 110, "Amnt": 150 }, { "NO": 142, "Amnt": 263 }] }];
        for (var t in test)
        {
            var obj = test[t];
            console.log(obj.Invoice.NO);
            console.log(obj.Invoice.$$hashKey);
            for ( var cst in obj.Cost)
            {
                console.log("Cost Value: " + obj.Cost[cst].NO + " " + obj.Cost[cst].Amnt);
            }
        }
```